# After upgrading to Excel 2016 I am getting "5 Invalid procure call or argument" on my VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim WbookCheck As Workbook

On Error Resume Next
Set WbookCheck = Workbooks("BOMCKTMP.xlsm")  *<--debug highlights this as the issue.*

If WbookCheck Is Nothing Then 'Closed
```

Comment: Do your debug settings have "Break on All Errors"?

Comment: It is set to Break on Unhandled errors.

Comment: Can you show your full code? Or, preferably a [mcve]? The snippet you show above is not enough to diagnose whatever's going on here :)

Comment: Nope. Please edit your question and include the code there where it can be properly rendered. Comments are not the place to put multi-line code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Go into VBA (by hitting Alt-F11), go to Tools | References and make sure you are still referencing the Excel object library.  If you are not, just select it and you will be good to go.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Under Tools --> References... you one of the options selected should include "Microsoft Excel xx.x Object Library" where xx.x is your version of excel. 
(This usually is a default setting so it should already be checked)

After that double check to ensure "BOMCKTMP.xlsm" is a workbook that is actually open.  If it is NOT open the application Excel will not be able to "see" this particular workbook within its 'Workbooks' collection of objects.

If you need to open the "BOMCKTMP.xlsm" and you know it is always going to be in the same place you can use: 
    `Workbooks.Open` 
Read about it via MSDN to learn how to include its specific filepath.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-open-method-excel

Comment: If the workbook isn't open, this line *shouldn't* normally raise an error here because of `On Error Resume Next`. Something else is going on, perhaps in debugging settings OP has "Break on all errors"?

Comment: Also, workbook that isn't opened would raise Subscript out of Range error.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I've never had to have the workbook open before, but have tried so after receiving the error.  Still happens.  Correct reference is checked as displayed above.  In the Options, under Error trapping, it has Break on Unhandled Errors selected.  This worked for the past 3 months, the problem started when we rolled out Windows 10.